# How to use Stack in a Tab Navigator

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm new to react native. May I know how can I use Stack Navigator in Tab Navigator? I'm trying to hide the 'Add Budget' class component and insert into 'Budget' component but I tried this way it doesn't work it shows `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.key')`

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Add Budget" component={addBudget}/>
        </Stack.Navigator> 
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={getTransaction} />
        
        <Tab.Screen name="Budget" component={budget} />
        
        <Tab.Screen name="Register" component={register} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Login" component={login} />
        <Tab.Screen name="TransactionDetails" component={transactionDetails} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={profile} />
        <Tab.Screen name="CSV" component={exportToCSV} />
        
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

in budget page when tap the FAB it should navigate to 'add budget' page instead of manually tapping the 'add budget'page from the bottom navigation

```
<FAB
   style={styles.fab}
   icon="plus"
   color="#5FC5FF"
   onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Add Budget")}
/>
```

[image: here]